# Problem in Combinatorics, ways to complete a course

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Assume we have a course with 7 weeks. Each week has 8 exercises in it. In order to pass the course, 5 exercises out of the 8 must be done each week. The order of the exercises done in each week don't matter, any one of the 8 can be done. How many combinations are there to complete the course, when the total exercises done is n where n is in the range (35 - 56)?

For example, 42 is supposed to give 2375030784000 in different ways.

A mathematical explanation for this would be much appreciated!

EDIT: I solved the problem using the following code. Basically what I do here, is check if there are any extra remaining exercises to be shared among the 7 weeks. If there are, I created an algorithm that give a list of lists containing every single way there is to distribute the remaining exercises to the weeks. I named them candies just for fun. After that I looped over every single list of combinations, and calculated combinations in each week. In the end I returned the sum of all the combinations. If my verbal explanation wasn't good enough (I didn't proof read this :)) run the code yourself and see how it works.

```
from math import comb


def count(x):

if x > 56 or x < 35:
    return 0

remaining = x - 35

if remaining == 0:
    return comb(8,5)**7


def distribute_candies(n, num_people, candies, result, current_distribution):
    if num_people == 0:
        if candies == 0:
            result.append(list(current_distribution))
        return

    for i in range(min(candies, 3) + 1):
        current_distribution.append(i)
        distribute_candies(n, num_people - 1, candies - i, result, current_distribution)
        current_distribution.pop()

def get_candy_distributions(n):
    result = []
    distribute_candies(n, 7, n, result, [])
    return result

distributions = get_candy_distributions(remaining)


answers = []

for distribution in distributions:
    answer = 1
    for extra_candy in distribution:
        answer *= comb(8,5+extra_candy)
    answers.append(answer)


return sum(answers)


            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(count(35)) # 1727094849536
    print(count(42)) # 2375030784000
    print(count(55)) # 56
    print(count(56)) # 1
    print(count(80)) # 0
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145865/discussion-on-question-by-m-problem-in-combinatorics-ways-to-complete-a-cours); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.